Obtain phase spectrum from frequency/phase modulated signal
I have a homodyne rf setup in which I measure spectra by stepping frequency by frequency. The phase reference resets every time I change the signal frequency, so I can only measure the amplitude, but not the phase spectrum.
My idea was to use FM or PM around a center frequency. I suppose that the phase trajectory of the output contains information about the slope of the phase spectrum, additionally to the evolution due to the modulation itself. However, I am unable to find the correct relations that would yield the (slope of the) phase spectrum given the I,Q(t) samples recorded at the output.

bit confused: in a homodyne receiver, you can't step the frequency at all – the received carrier defines your tuning. Can you maybe elaborate a bit more (in your question) about the system you're building?

What I wanted to express is that I have a signal generator and a digitizer, both having a local oscillator. The data acquired by the digitizer are time-traced samples of I/Q data. Both signal generator and digitizer have variable frequency, such that I can acquire some I/Q data at one frequency, calculate the mean amplitude, and then move on to the next frequency, eventually producing an amplitude spectrum. From the I/Q, the phase can be calculated as well, but since phase reference is lost after stepping the frequency, it is essentially meaningless. Thus the idea with FM/PM.
